# Multicolor titles with ggplot2 for R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to implement multicolor texts as shown here:

[multicolor text on chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258101/multicolor-text-on-chart)

which referenced this:

[multicolor text in R](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/multicolor-text-in-r.html)

This is what I came up with (with help from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/54q_qdTE1L0)):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
png(file="multicolortitle.png",width=800,height=500)
qplot(x = hp,y = mpg,data = mtcars,color=factor(mtcars$cyl),size=2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red3","green3","blue3")) + 
  theme_bw() +
  opts(title = " \n ") +
  opts(legend.position = "none") 
spacing  <- 20
grid.text(0.5, unit(1,"npc") - unit(1,"line"), 
          label=paste("4 cylinder,",paste(rep(" ",spacing*2), collapse='')),
          gp=gpar(col="red3", fontsize=16,fontface="bold"))
grid.text(0.5, unit(1,"npc") - unit(1,"line"), 
          label=paste(paste(rep(" ",spacing), collapse=''),"6 cylinder,",
            paste(rep(" ",spacing), collapse='')),
          gp=gpar(col="green3", fontsize=16,fontface="bold"))
grid.text(0.5, unit(1,"npc") - unit(1,"line"), 
          label=paste(paste(rep(" ",spacing*2), collapse=''),"8 cylinder"),
          gp=gpar(col="blue3", fontsize=16,fontface="bold"))
grid.text(0.5, unit(1,"npc") - unit(2,"line"), 
          label=paste(paste(rep(" ",spacing*0), collapse=''),
            "- Horsepower versus Miles per Gallon"),
          gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=16,fontface="bold"))
dev.off()
```

Here's the resulting graph:

[image: Horsepower versus Miles per Gallon by # Cylinders (mtcars data-set)]

So, my question: is there a more elegant method to use for this? I'd like to be able to use `ggsave` for example, and creating the spacing for this is a highly manual process - not suited for scenarios where I need to automatically make hundreds of plots of this nature. I could see writing some functions on top of this, but maybe there's a better way to implement the methods utilized with the base plotting function?

Comment: Would you like to make the colours automaticly be the same as in the plot?

Comment: I think that would be good, granted I think you could just made the 'values' in 'scale_colour_manual' a vector and then just call values[1] and so on, maybe append black so it would be values[4]. It would be cool to have it where it could pull the colors used in the plot even if there were not manually selected and I'm not sure how I'd go about that yet but I bet that's documented somewhere :/.

Comment: Welcome to the R community of Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a more general approach that takes advantage of a few additional **grid** functions. It's not particularly well-polished, but it may give you some useful ideas:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(mpg,hp,color=factor(cyl),size=2)) + 
       geom_point() + theme_bw() +
       opts(title = " \n ") + opts(legend.position="none")

## Get factor levels 
levs <- levels(factor(mtcars$cyl))
n <- length(levs)

## Get factors' plotting colors
g <- ggplot_build(p)
d <- unique(g$data[[1]][c("colour", "group")])
cols <- d$colour[order(d$group)]

## Use widest label's width to determine spacing
labs <- paste(levs, "cylinder")
xlocs <- unit(0.5, "npc") + 
         1.1 * (seq_len(n) - mean(seq_len(n))) * max(unit(1, "strwidth", labs))

## Plot labels in top 10% of device
pushViewport(viewport(y=0.95, height=0.1))
    grid.text(paste(levs, "cylinder"), 
              x = xlocs, y=unit(0.5, "lines"), 
              gp = gpar(col=cols, fontface="bold"))
    grid.text("- Horsepower versus Miles per Gallon", 
              y = unit(-0.5, "lines"))
upViewport()

## Plot main figure in bottom 90% of device
pushViewport(viewport(y=0.45, height=0.9))
    print(p, newpage=FALSE)
upViewport()
```

Comment: thanks, that's great. it looks like it automatically works for when you have more than 3 groups in the title

Answer (score 1):

A possible strategy wrapping the words in a dummy table,

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
title = c('Concentration of ','affluence',' and ','poverty',' nationwide')
colors = c('black', '#EEB422','black', '#238E68','black')

grid.arrange(ggplot(), 
             top = tableGrob(t(title), 
                             theme=ttheme_minimal(padding=unit(c(0,2),'mm'),
                                                  base_colour = colors)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue017.png)