# Color individual words in title to match colors of groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently saw a line chart in the Economist where the [title had colored words to match the colors of the groups used in the line chart](https://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2018/04/daily-chart-1).  I was wondering how to do this with a ggplot2 object.  Here is some code to make a line chart with everything like the econimist article except the colored words in the title.  At the bottom I show the desired output.

**This question is not about theoretical ways to display this info (like directly labeling or a legend) but rather specifically about coloring individual words in titles.**

```
data <- data.frame(
    group = rep(c('affluence', 'poverty'), each = 6),
    year = rep(c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2012), 2),  
    concentration = c(.125, .12, .14, .13, .145, .146, .068, .09, .125, .119, .13, .135)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(year, concentration, color = group)) +
    geom_line(size = 1.5) +
    geom_point(size = 4) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, .15)) +
    labs(
        x = NULL, y = NULL, 
        title = 'Concentration of affluence and poverty nationwide'
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.position = 'none'
    ) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('#EEB422', '#238E68'))
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105646/1412059

Comment: How is the mentioned answer constructive to make a `black yellow black green black` main title?

Comment: @AndreElrico It illustrates that you can turn a ggplot into a grid object and then edit the label. It's not an exact duplicate but the principle is the same. Note that details might differ anyway in the current ggplot2 version.

Comment: @Roland Saidly it does not work for me anymore: `Error in set.gpar(x$gp) : argument must be a 'gpar' object`

Comment: well if the mentioned way is the only way, better export to `pdf` and use `inkscape`.

Comment: Dupe-oids: [Multicolor titles with ggplot2 for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976590/multicolor-titles-with-ggplot2-for-r); [Multicolored title with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321483/multicolored-title-with-r)

Comment: @Henrik I would say that truly is a dupe

Comment: @TylerRinker OK! I didn't find those when I was digging around before I started with my answer. I just close then...

Comment: @Henrik Yeah and I'm still glad I asked b/c your answer is better IMO than the linked to question.

Comment: also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852882/use-different-font-sizes-for-different-portions-of-text-in-ggplot2-title

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solution is based on [Displaying text below the plot generated by ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2) and [Colorize parts of the title in a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083362/colorize-parts-of-the-title-in-a-plot) (credits to the contributors there!).

By using `phantom` placeholders for text, we avoid (most of the) hardcoding of positions.

```
# create text grobs, one for each color
library(grid)
t1 <- textGrob(expression("Concentration of " * phantom(bold("affluence")) * "and" * phantom(bold("poverty")) * " nationwide"),
               x = 0.5, y = 1.1, gp = gpar(col = "black"))

t2 <- textGrob(expression(phantom("Concentration of ") * bold("affluence") * phantom(" and poverty nationwide")),
               x = 0.5, y = 1.1, gp = gpar(col = "#EEB422"))

t3 <- textGrob(expression(phantom("Concentration of affluence and ") * bold("poverty") * phantom(" nationwide")),
               x = 0.5, y = 1.1, gp = gpar(col = "#238E68"))

# plot and add grobs with annotation_custom
ggplot(data, aes(year, concentration, color = group)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  annotation_custom(grobTree(t1, t2, t3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.15)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#EEB422", "#238E68")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        # add some extra margin on top
        plot.margin = unit(c(4, 1, 1, 1), "lines"))
```

[image]

---

With a larger number of colored words, the creation of the different `expression`s should be done more programmatically. See e.g. the nice `multiTitle` function in a similar question for `base` plot: [title: words in different colors?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-January/378653.html), which should be useful in `ggplot` as well.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a simple and more general way using the `ggtext` package

[image]

produced with:

```
library(ggtext) 

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = NULL,
    values = c(setosa = "#0072B2", virginica = "#009E73", versicolor = "#D55E00"),
    labels = c(
      setosa = "<i style='color:#0072B2'>I. setosa</i>",
      virginica = "<i style='color:#009E73'>I. virginica</i>",
      versicolor = "<i style='color:#D55E00'>I. versicolor</i>")
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "**Fisher's *Iris* dataset**  
    <span style='font-size:11pt'>Sepal width vs. sepal length for 
    <span style='color:#0072B2;'>setosa</span>, 
    <span style='color:#D55E00;'>versicolor</span>, and
    <span style='color:#009E73;'>virginica</span>
    </span>",
    x = "Sepal length (cm)", y = "Sepal width (cm)"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_markdown(lineheight = 1.1),
    legend.text = element_markdown(size = 11)
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat cumbersome solution with `annotation_custom`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(year, concentration, color = group)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.16)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = ' ') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#EEB422', '#238E68')) +
  annotation_custom(textGrob('Concentration of', gp = gpar(col = 'black')), 
                    xmin = 1972, xmax = 1972, ymin = 0.165, ymax = 0.165) +
  annotation_custom(textGrob('affluence', gp = gpar(col = '#EEB422', fontface = 'bold')), 
                    xmin = 1975.7, xmax = 1975.7, ymin = 0.165, ymax = 0.165) +
  annotation_custom(textGrob(' and ', gp = gpar(col = 'black')), 
                    xmin = 1977.65, xmax = 1977.65, ymin = 0.165, ymax = 0.165) +
  annotation_custom(textGrob('poverty', gp = gpar(col = '#238E68', fontface = 'bold')), 
                    xmin = 1979.35, xmax = 1979.35, ymin = 0.165, ymax = 0.165) +
  annotation_custom(textGrob('nationwide', gp = gpar(col = 'black')), 
                    xmin = 1982, xmax = 1982, ymin = 0.165, ymax = 0.165)
```

which gives:

[image]

Main drawback of this approach is that it requires a lot fiddling with the parameters to get the words of the title on the right spots.