# Control text size after line break in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to give different sizes on Stackoverflow and Example in the x label text?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + labs(x = 'Stackoverflow\nexample')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different font sizes for different portions of text in ggplot2 title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852882/use-different-font-sizes-for-different-portions-of-text-in-ggplot2-title)

Answer (score 1):

Use `draw_label()` from `cowplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() +
  xlab("") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, # you don't need to define size actually
# margin is important to give you some space on the bottom
                                    margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0,
                                                    unit = "mm"))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  draw_label("Stackoverflow", x = 3.25, y = 3.5, size = 15) + 
# play with x,y to center the text
  draw_label("example", x = 3.25, y = 3.25, size = 10)
```

[image]