# Apply bold font on specific axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

ggplot(head(mtcars) %>% rownames_to_column("cars"),
       aes(x = reorder(cars, - drat), 
           y = drat)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

How can I apply bold font on specific car names (for example just on "Hornet 4 Drive" and "Datsun 710")?

I would prefer a quite "general" answer, i.e an answer that makes it easy to apply a particular color or another font family instead of bold font.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ggtext` allows you to use markdown and html tags for axis labels and other text. So we can create a function to pass to the `labels` argument of `scale_y_discrete` (as @RomanLuštrik suggested in their comment), through which we can select the labels to highlight, the color, and the font family:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)

highlight = function(x, pat, color="black", family="") {
  ifelse(grepl(pat, x), glue("<b style='font-family:{family}; color:{color}'>{x}</b>"), x)
}

head(mtcars) %>% rownames_to_column("cars") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = reorder(cars, - drat), 
             x = drat)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels= function(x) highlight(x, "Datsun 710|Hornet 4", "red")) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_markdown())
```

[image]

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=function(x) highlight(x, "setosa", "purple", "Copperplate")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_markdown(size=15))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, only drawback I see for now is that CRAN version of `ggtext` is not available on R 4.0.0 (unless I have a problem with my R installation)

Comment: I'm not running R 4.0.0 yet, but maybe try installing the development version of ggtext: `remotes::install_github("wilkelab/ggtext")`.

Comment: In your answer, you inverted the `x` and `y` coordinates in `aes()` and you removed `coord_flip()`. If I invert these coordinates back (as in my post) and use `coord_flip()`, your code does not work anymore. Though this is not a big problem, I think it is worth mentioning in your answer

Comment: In the current version of ggplot2, you don't need to specify `coord_flip`. If you map the discrete variable to the y-axis`, ggplot will automatically render the plot as a horizontal plot.

Answer (score 7):

It would seem there's an easier way to approach this (no need to make your own labeller). Just specify specific face of the label in `theme(axis.text.y)`. Notice that I had to define the x axis values as a factor to make order of labels predictable.

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$cars <- as.factor(rownames(mtcars))
bold.cars <- c("Merc 280", "Fiat 128")

bold.labels <- ifelse(levels(mtcars$cars) %in% bold.cars, yes = "bold", no = "plain")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cars, y = drat)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = bold.labels)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: It works but produces a warning: ```Warning message:
Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2. ``` Do you know if it is possible to fix it?

Comment: I get no warnings running the code above. `ggplot2` version 3.2.1.

Comment: I have a warning with `ggplot2` 3.3.0

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use `expression` in a labels argument.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

ggplot(head(mtcars) %>% rownames_to_column("cars"),
       aes(x = reorder(cars, - drat), 
           y = drat)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Mazda RX4",
                              "Mazda RX4 Wag",
                              expression(bold("Datsun 710")),
                              expression(bold("Hornet 4 Drive")),
                              "Hornet Sportabout",
                              "Valiant")) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

If you wanted to do this in an automated way, you could define a custom bolding function to make the expression:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

MakeExp <- function(x,y){
  exp <- vector(length = 0, mode = "expression")
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (i %in% y) exp[[i]] <- bquote(bold(.(x[i])))
    else exp[[i]] <- x[i]
  }
return(exp)
}

ggplot(head(mtcars) %>% rownames_to_column("cars"),
       aes(x = reorder(cars, - drat), 
           y = drat)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = MakeExp(rownames(head(mtcars)),c(3,4))) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: One drawback of this approach is that you need to write all the names of the cars (in this example), is it possible only to apply bold font to some car names?

Comment: @bretauv my guess is that this is possible through a custom labeller function.

Comment: @bretauv I edited my answer to give an example of a custom label expression function.

Comment: Your edit improved your answer, but still this requires to know the row number corresponding to the car name, which I found quite annoying when you have a lot of names

Comment: You could easily change `y` to be the names you want to bold and the if statement to `if (x[i] %in% y)`.

Comment: Indeed, I see that you can replace `bold` by `italic` to put those names in italic font, but can you change their color?

Comment: `plotmath` doesn't seem to manage colors unfortunately. I would probably go for an approach like [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735290/) for colors.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer anyway (@eipi10's answer allows color-formatting if you're interested)

Answer (score 2):

An "automated" (semi) approach that will throw a warning(see later, see [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3492)):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

custom_face <- ifelse(row.names(mtcars) %in% c("Hornet 4 Drive","Datsun 710"),
                      "bold","plain")
head(mtcars) %>% rownames_to_column("cars") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(cars, - drat), 
           y = drat)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face=custom_face))
```

**Warning**(it is unclear to me from the discussion on the linked issue what the final decision regarding this "feature"'s future was)

> Warning message:
>   Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
>   Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: I have the error `Error in element_text(face = custom_face): object 'custom_face' not found` (in a new session)

Comment: Did you run the code as it is in this answer? Oh, let me edit. I had defined some other test function elswhere

Comment: Yes I copied and pasted your code in a new session (just added the necessary `library()` calls)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited and it should work now. Anyway, a similar answer has been added although I had answered this earlier.