# How do I make ggplot2 custom text formats from axis scale functions follow format specifications set in theme()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change scientific notation on ggplot2 axes from a format like `3.23e+6` to `3.23 × 10^6`.  Thankfully this question has been answered here: [How do I change the formatting of numbers on an axis with ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610377/how-do-i-change-the-formatting-of-numbers-on-an-axis-with-ggplot)

It works well for basic cases. However, it does not work when you want to change the formatting of the axis label. This is illustrated by this example:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy*10^9)) + geom_point()

#makes the scientific notation using "AeB" explicitly write out Ax10^B
fancy_scientific <- function(l) {
  # turn in to character string in scientific notation
  l <- format(l, scientific = TRUE)
  # quote the part before the exponent to keep all the digits
  l <- gsub("^(.*)e", "'\\1'e", l)
  # turn the 'e+' into plotmath format
  l <- gsub("e", "%*%10^", l)
  # return this as an expression
  parse(text=l)
}


ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy*10^9)) + 
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels= fancy_scientific)  +
 theme(text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Which yields:

[image]

The problem is that the Y axis text is not bold as specified in the call to `theme`.  When I use `browser` to see what is happening inside of `fancy_scientific` I see that it returns an object of class "expression" which in this case is printed as
`expression('2'%*%10^+01, '3'%*%10^+01, '4'%*%10^+01)`  while the function `scales::scientific` , which can be used to force scientific notation of the kind I want to avoid but conforms to whatever theme specifications I set, returns a vector of strings directly. When I modify `fancy_scientific` to return a vector of strings like `'2'%*%10^+01` they are directly rendered to the displayed Y axis.

So the question is how do I make the output of the `fancy_scientific` function conform to my theme specification?

Comment: Have you tried setting `bold` inside the `expression`? For example, `expression(bold("label"))`

Comment: Even if I could make this work it wouldn't help because I want to control everything fro the ```theme()``` function.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733297/apply-bold-font-on-specific-axis-ticks

Comment: Asked followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497825/what-formatting-language-does-ggtext-use-to-format-text .  Didn't accept my own answer in case someone comes along with a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this, as suggested by the comment is the `ggtext` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy*10^9)) + geom_point()


#makes the scientific notation using "AeB" explicitly write out Ax10^B
fancy_scientific <- function(l) {
  # turn in to character string in scientific notation
  l <- format(l, scientific = TRUE)
  # quote the part before the exponent to keep all the digits
  l <- gsub("^(.*)e", "'\\1'e", l)
  # turn the 'e+' into plotmath format
  l <- gsub("e", "%*%10^", l)
  # return this as an expression
  parse(text=l)
}


ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy*10^9)) + 
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels= fancy_scientific)  +
  theme(text = element_text(face = "bold"), 
        axis.text.y = element_markdown(face = "bold"))
```

If you run this code though, you will notice some problems.  There are quotes around the leading number, which can be gotten rid of by deleting the single quotes in `l <- gsub("^(.*)e", "'\\1'e", l)`.  I get an error when I specify `text` as `element_markdown()` because apparently there are some defaults that need to be set for other parts of the text. So I have to specifically set `axis.text.y` as `element_markdown`.  This leaves the issue of getting a real times sign to display. I will ask a follow up question about this because I have answered the question of how to get the bold formatting to apply, though I am also curious about how to set the defaults to `element_markdown` correctly so that I can use it to specify `text` rather than `axis.text.y`.