# Trying to have a multicolor label in my plot(using R)

Tags: r, plot

Im trying to have a 3 colors labels in my plot in R language, but i dont seems to be able to. I have tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258101/multicolor-text-on-chart), dont seems to work for my problem. Here is the code to generate my plot:

```
pdf("report/500ERR_plots.pdf", width=10, height=7)

allDataTable_500$Date <- as.Date(allDataTable_500$Date)

totalTs <- allDataTable_500$Total

plot(allDataTable_500$Date, allDataTable_500$Total, xlab="Date", ylab="Total", las=2, xaxt="n", type="o", xlim=as.Date(c(allDataTable_500$Date[1], allDataTable_500$Date[16])), ylim=c(0, max(totalTs) + 200), cex = 0.8)
axis.Date(side = 1, at = as.Date(allDataTable_500$Date), format = "%d %b", las=2, cex = 0.1)
grid(NULL, NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "dashed", lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)
title(main=paste("All 500 Errors from ", allDataTable_500$Date[1], " to ", allDataTable_500$Date[16], "\nReport generated on ", allDataTable_500$Date[16], " at ", allDataTable_500$ProducedAt[1]), col.main="red", font.main=2)
text(x = allDataTable_500$Date, y = allDataTable_500$Total, label = paste(allDataTable_500$Total , "\n", totalRequestDataTable$Total,"\n(",round((allDataTable_500$Total / totalRequestDataTable$Total * 100), 3), "%)"), pos = 3, cex = 0.7, col = "blue")
```

Here is how the labels looks at the moment: [labelExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir6pW.png)
I want the first line of the label to be red, the second to be blue and the third one to be black, is this feasable?

PS: I've already tried to add multiple colors to the col argument but Rstudio does not output the graph that i want. Here what it look like with multiple color in the col argument: [MultipleColorPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D7mW.png). For example, where the peak is on this graph i would like the 184 to be red, the 452964 to be blue and the (0.041%) to be black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the labels in the three groups and add 3 labels and adjust them with an **offset**:

Or you could also use `ggplot2` and `ggrepel`, which will adjust the labels if they overlap.

```
allDataTable_500 <- data.frame(
  Date = runif(10, 1, 100),
  Total = runif(10, 100, 400)
)

plot(allDataTable_500$Date, 
     allDataTable_500$Total, xlab="Date", ylab="Total", las=2, xaxt="n", type="o", 
     cex = 0.8)
axis(side = 1, at = (allDataTable_500$Date), cex = 0.1)
grid(NULL, NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "dashed", lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)

text(x = allDataTable_500$Date, y = allDataTable_500$Total, 
     label = paste(allDataTable_500$Total , "\n"), 
     pos = 3, cex = 0.7, 
     col = c("black"))

text(x = allDataTable_500$Date, y = allDataTable_500$Total, 
     label = paste(allDataTable_500$Total , "\n"), 
     pos = 3, cex = 0.7, offset = 1, 
     col = c("blue"))

text(x = allDataTable_500$Date, y = allDataTable_500$Total, 
     label = paste(allDataTable_500$Total , "\n"), 
     pos = 3, cex = 0.7, offset = 1.5, 
     col = c("red"))
```

Comment: Hello, i've already tried that solution and Rstudio does not output what i really want. I've updated my post for your better understanding. But basically i want to "split" the label by color(between each "\n"). Thanks for your interest in my problem by the way!

Comment: I just included another idea. But could you include a fraction of your data, so you're code is reproducible? That would make it much easier.

Comment: Your second solution is working greate mate! Thank you VERY much.